# exim route file condition

Tags: exim, conditional

Using exim4 I have set up a route to use an external SMTP server. I am using cPanel which keeps a list of domains set up locally on the server in the file: /etc/localdomains . As a result I have set up a condition to only send through this relay if the sender address domain is in this file. This works just fine.

However now I want to add another condition that ensures that if a domain is listed in a file say /etc/norelaydomains it should NOT be sent using the relay. I thought it would be an easy matter to get this to work by adding a similar condition to the one ensuring the domain is in /etc/localdomains, however this does not seem to work correctly (no mail sent using the relay).

To recap what I want is: if sender_domain is IN /etc/localdomains and sender_domain is NOT IN /etc/norelaydomains then send using relay, otherwise send using local mail server.

My normal setup that works fine is:

```
my_route:
  condition = ${lookup {$sender_address_domain} \ 
lsearch {/etc/localdomains} {yes}}
  driver = manualroute
  domains = !+local_domains
  transport = my_relay
  route_list = * mysmtp.com
```

The setup I have attempted (using this no mails go through the relay)

```
my_route:
  condition = ${lookup {$sender_address_domain} \ 
lsearch {/etc/localdomains} {yes}}
  condition = ${lookup{$sender_address_domain} \
lsearch{/etc/norelaydomains} {no}}
  driver = manualroute
  domains = !+local_domains
  transport = my_relay
  route_list = * mysmtp.com
```

Any help on getting this to work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Everything looks fine except the line splitting. Are you sure you haven't trailing spaces after ` \\`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it.

Your problem is in the incomplete result substitution.

`${lookup{value}lsearch{file}}` by default returns the string been found or the empty string. You can modify that behaviour by result substitution:

`${lookup{value}lsearch{file}{yes}}`

That version returns `yes` if value has been found in the file and the empty string otherwise. But exim's condition evaluation treat as logical TRUE only 'yes', 'true' and nonzero positives. Therefore

`${lookup{value}lsearch{file}{no}}`

is equivalent to the

`${lookup{value}lsearch{file}{no}{no}}`

Always. Sure, your router will never be used. You have to substitute both results explicitly:

```
my_route:
  condition = ${lookup {$sender_address_domain}lsearch{/etc/localdomains} {yes}{no}}
  condition = ${lookup {$sender_address_domain}lsearch{/etc/norelaydomains} {no}{yes}}
  driver = manualroute
  domains = !+local_domains
  transport = my_relay
  route_list = * mysmtp.com
```